# Script backup a website with its databases

Tags: sql, linux, bash, web

This is the code, the idea is to backup a site in the days established in the array (in this test i have put all 7 days):

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

### Setup Environment ###
DIRS="INFO"
BACKUP=/tmp/backup.$$
NOW=$(date +"%d-%m-%Y")
INCFILE="/root/tar-inc-backup.dat"
DAY=$(date +"%a")
FULLBACKUP="Sun"
DAYSOFBACKUP=( Mon Tue Wed Thu Fri Sat Sun)

### MySQL Config ###
MUSER="INFO"
MPASS="INFO"
MHOST="INFO"
MYSQL="$(which mysql)"
MYSQLDUMP="$(which mysqldump)"
GZIP="$(which gzip)"

### FTP Config ###
FTPD="/"
FTPU="INFO"
FTPP="INFO"
FTPS="INFO"

### Email Config ###
EMAILID="INFO"

### FS Backup ###
[ ! -d $BACKUP ] && mkdir -p $BACKUP || :

### Determine which backup to run ###
for day in ${DAYSOFBACKUP[@]}
do
  if [ $day == "$FULLBACKUP" ]; then
    i=$(date +"%Hh%Mm%Ss")
    FTPD="/full"
    FILE="fs-full-$NOW.tar.gz"
    tar -zcvf $BACKUP/$FILE $DIRS
  else
    i=$(date +"%Hh%Mm%Ss")
    FILE="fs-i-$NOW-$i.tar.gz"
    sudo tar -g $INCFILE -zcvf $BACKUP/$FILE $DIRS
  fi
done

### Start MySQL Backup ###
# Get all databases name
DBS="$($MYSQL -u $MUSER -h $MHOST -p$MPASS -Bse 'show databases')"
for db in $DBS
do
if [ db == "bricalia_tienda" ]; then
 FILE=$BACKUP/mysql-$db.$NOW-$i.gz
 $MYSQLDUMP -u $MUSER -h $MHOST -p$MPASS $db | $GZIP -9 > $FILE
fi
done

### FTP Backup to Remote Server ###
#Start FTP backup using ncftp
ftp $FTPS $MUSER $MPASS
bin
sudo mkdir $FTPD
sudo mkdir $FTPD/$NOW
cd $FTPD/$NOW
lcd $BACKUP
mput *
quit

### Backup Fail Check ###
if [ "$?" == "0" ]; then
 rm -f $BACKUP/*
else
 T=/tmp/backup.fail
 echo "Date: $(date)">$T
 echo "Hostname: $(hostname)" >>$T
 echo "Backup failed" >>$T
 mail  -s "BACKUP FAILED" "$EMAILID" <$T
 rm -f $T
fi
```

I have an error in "Determine which backup to run in the if clause". It also has a problem in the last line: unexpected end.

The script is explained here: http://piratecove.org/website-backup-script/

Comment: Your here document syntax is broken.  Presumably it should be `ftp $FTPS<<EOF`, no?

As far as the fact that you have "an error" elsewhere in the script, the solution is going to depend in very sensitive ways on what that error is...

Comment: I have edited that, but that wasn't still the problem

Comment: You're missing a semi-colon before `do`.

Comment: Take a look at automysqlbackup and rsnapshot as well.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like, immediately below that comment you reference, is a duplicated line.  The if check:

```
### Determine which backup to run ###
if [ "$DAY" == "$FULLBACKUP" ]; then
if [ $day == "$FULLBACKUP" ]; then
```

I would guess removing the second if check would help.

Comment: It was an error copying the code. Now I have edited it. Same problem.

Answer (score 1):

After the "fix", there's another issue:

```
### Determine which backup to run ###
for day in ${DAYSOFBACKUP[@]} do
if [ $day == "$FULLBACKUP" ]; then
  i=$(date +"%Hh%Mm%Ss")
  FTPD="/full"
  FILE="fs-full-$NOW.tar.gz"
  tar -zcvf $BACKUP/$FILE $DIRS
else
  i=$(date +"%Hh%Mm%Ss")
  FILE="fs-i-$NOW-$i.tar.gz"
  tar -g $INCFILE -zcvf $BACKUP/$FILE $DIRS
fi
```

This for loop isn't right, try this:

```
### Determine which backup to run ###
for day in ${DAYSOFBACKUP[@]}
do
  if [ $day == "$FULLBACKUP" ]; then
    i=$(date +"%Hh%Mm%Ss")
    FTPD="/full"
    FILE="fs-full-$NOW.tar.gz"
    tar -zcvf $BACKUP/$FILE $DIRS
  else
    i=$(date +"%Hh%Mm%Ss")
    FILE="fs-i-$NOW-$i.tar.gz"
    tar -g $INCFILE -zcvf $BACKUP/$FILE $DIRS
  fi
done
```

Comment: Changed, that code worked. Now problem is in #Start FTP backup using ncftp
ftp $FTPS< prompt

Comment: What is "the problem"?  Error messages or anything?

Comment: ./backup.sh: líne 80: warning:document in line 60 is delimited by end-of-file (expected `EOF')

Comment: There's a "here document".  Try moving the final EOF to a new line, details here: http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/here-docs.html

Comment: That solves the error, but now the terminal asks me for a password of the ftp and takes my system user as the ftp user

Comment: The ftp application should support a command called 'user'.  Try adding:

user [username] [password]

To the ftp script, should authenticate without prompting you.

Comment: Now edited that part. Now it shows the "ftp > " terminal and I can type. What I want is to copy the / content of the ftp to the foler named with de date.